# Creating parametrized Matlab unittest with complicated properties

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, parameterized-unit-test

I'm trying to create a parametrized Matlab unittest where the `TestParameter` properties are generated "dynamically" by some code (e.g., with a `for` loop).

As a simplified example, suppose my code is

```
classdef partest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    properties (TestParameter)
        level = struct('level1', 1, 'level2', 2, 'level3', 3, 'level4', 4)
    end

    methods (Test)
        function testModeling(testCase, level)
            fprintf('Testing level %d\n', level);
        end
    end
end
```

but in my real code, I have 100 levels. I tried to put this in a separate method, like

```
classdef partest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods (Static)
        function level = getLevel()
            for i=1:100
               level.(sprintf('Level%d', i)) = i;
            end
        end
    end

    properties (TestParameter)
        level = partest.getLevel()
    end

    methods (Test)
        function testModeling(testCase, level)
            fprintf('Testing level %d\n', level);
        end
    end
end
```

but that does not work; I get the error (Matlab 2014b):

```
>> runtests partest
Error using matlab.unittest.TestSuite.fromFile (line 163)
The class partest has no property or method named 'getLevel'.
```

I could move the `getLevel()` function to another file, but I'd like to keep it in one file.

Comment: I can not run your code because my matlab version is to old, but you could try `level = cell2struct(num2cell(1:n), arrayfun(@(x)(['level',num2str(x)]),1:n,'uni',false), 2)` in your original class.

Comment: @Daniel: of course my real example is more complicated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same here (R2015b), it looks like a `TestParameter` property cannot be initialized with a static function call...

Fortunately the solution is quite simple, use a [local function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) instead:

#### partest.m

```
classdef partest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    properties (TestParameter)
        level = getLevel()
    end

    methods (Test)
        function testModeling(testCase, level)
            fprintf('Testing level %d\n', level);
        end
    end
end

function level = getLevel()
    for i=1:100
       level.(sprintf('Level%d', i)) = i;
    end
end
```

(Note that all the above code is contained in one file `partest.m`).

Now this should work:

```
>> run(matlab.unittest.TestSuite.fromFile('partest.m'))
```

---

**Note**:

Being a local function, it won't be visible outside the class. If you also need to expose it, just add a static function acting as a simple wrapper:

```
classdef partest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    ...

    methods (Static)
        function level = GetLevelFunc()
            level = getLevel();
        end
    end
end

function level = getLevel()
    ...
end
```

Comment: Silly me with my Java background, I never realized I could make local functions in a `classdef`.

Comment: Here's an entry about it in the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-methods-and-functions.html#br2la89

Comment: This is a bug: you _should_ be able to define a `TestParameter` by calling a static method of the class. I've reported the bug to the development team to be fixed in a future release. In the meantime, using a local function, as Amro suggests, is a good workaround.

Comment: @DavidHruska: Thanks. Do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: @FrankMeulenaar: Here's the bug report: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1212962

Comment: This bug has been fixed as of R2016b.

Comment: @DavidHruska thanks for reporting the bug and following up.